# Categorizing in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables with me:

Interest Table:

```
Date    VisitorID   Interest
5/3    A             $30
5/4    C             $15
5/7    B             $21
```

Visitor Table:

```
VisitorID          InterestSegment
A              Simple
B              Compound
C              Simple
```

I need to query the 2 tables to show 'Simple' and 'Compound' segments by each day. The solution should look something like this:

```
Date    Total spend from Simple   Total spend from Compound
5/3          $30                        NULL
5/4          $15                        NULL
5/7          NULL                       $21
```

I tried using the following code but it doesn't categorize the way I want it. Also, I need to replace the $ by '' as the SUM function doesn't work on the varchar field.

```
SELECT p.Date, m.InterestSegment, SUM(REPLACE(p.Interest,'$',''))
FROM visitor as m
LEFT JOIN interest as p ON m.VisitorID = p.VisitorID
GROUP BY Date, InterestSegment, Interest
```

Comment: What is the purpose of including `Interest` into your `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: why is interest stored in a varchar?

Comment: It's the default table I received for homework. I think the prof wants to make it a bit complex for us while considering amount having $ vs just the integer

Comment: You mean the interest column really contains strings with a dollar sign inside? That would be a terrible table design. Maybe it's just a display thing? Which DBMS are you using? And what is the column's data type?

Comment: I know, it's a pain working with that $ sign. Maybe I could have added an assumption of INT column & proceeded with my queries but I have been using REPLACE(p.Interest,'$','') & it serves its purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
     SELECT p.Date, 
     SUM(case when InterestSegment='Simple' then Interest else 0 end) 
     Total_spend_from_Simple,
     SUM(case when InterestSegment='Compound' then Interest else 0 end) 
     Total_spend_from_Compound   
     FROM visitor as m
     JOIN interest as p ON m.VisitorID = p.VisitorID
     GROUP BY p.Date
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I just had to add REPLACE(p.Interest,'$','') as there $ on the amount column.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT p.date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.interestSegment = 'Simple' THEN p.interest END) "Total Spend From Simple",
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.interestSegment = 'Compound' THEN p.interest END) "Total Spend From Compound"
FROM INTEREST p, VISITORS m
WHERE p.visitorId = m.visitorId
GROUP BY p.date
```

Comment: Comma-separated joins were made redundant in 1992. Use proper ANSI joins instead.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you improved my knowledge about sql standards. Thanks.